# blueimp jquery file upload - issues with remote access

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'd using Jquery File Upload and I encounter some issues with when I'm working with a remote access.

Normally, the event list started with: -change -add ...etc ... and finished with : - always - stop - started - completed - finished - stopped.
But sometimes, after -stop nothing happened.

After many tests, I found a strange behavior. Sometimes, after I've selected some files, the process doesn't go to the end (- stopped), and the file uploaded is invisible but if I check the html code, I could see the ligne `<tr>` but her class is "template-download fade" and not "template-download fade in". And if you cheat a little and add "in" it's maggic!!! All the process go to the end.

Maybe I've done some mistake with the parameters but I checked all the topics about the plug-in and I didn't found any answer.

Here is my code:

```
 $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        url: "/upload/server/php/",
        dataType: "json",
        limitMultiFileUploadSize: 400971520,
        limitMultiFileUploadSizeOverhead: 400971520,
        maxFileSize: 400971520,
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/ .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(pdf|jpe?g|png|bmp|tif?f)$/i,
        autoUpload: true,
});
```

Maybe i need to tell you i work with zendFramework 2, php 5.6.

Comment: thanks for your correction cfnerd

Answer (score 0):

more information : the file is sent to the server and i've done some changes :

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
  url: "/upload/server/php/",
  dataType: "json",
  limitConcurrentUploads: 3,
  limitMultiFileUploadSize: 20971520,
  limitMultiFileUploadSizeOverhead: 20971520,
  maxFileSize: 20971520,
  formAcceptCharset: "utf-8",
  disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
  prependFiles: true,
  previewOrientation: true,
  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(pdf|jpe?g|png|bmp|tif?f)$/i,
  autoUpload: true
});
```

And :

```
$("#fileupload").bind("fileuploaddestroy", function (e, data) { 
   var numberOfFiles = $("#fileupload").fileupload("option").getNumberOfFiles();
   if(numberOfFiles > 0){
      $(".infoNum").text("Nombre de fichier : "+ (numberOfFiles-1));
   }else{
      $(".infoNum").text(""); 
   }
}).bind("fileuploadcompleted", function(e, data) {
   var numberOfFiles = $("#fileupload").fileupload("option").getNumberOfFiles(); 
   if(numberOfFiles > 0){ 
      $(".infoNum").text("Nombre de fichier : "+ numberOfFiles);
   }else{
      $(".infoNum").text("");
   }
}).bind("fileuploadstopped", function (e) {
   $("tr").each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("in") == false){
          $(this).addClass("in"); 
          console.log("done");
       }
});
```

i didn't find an another way for push to trigger completed.
Someone have an idea, please ?